# How to store a screen value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I'm making a calculator and I want to make it have MS(Memory store), MR(Memory Restore), and MC(Memory Clear). For memory store, I need to save the screen value of the calculation (so say 90 + 7 = 97 I need to save that), then have the ability to recall that using the MR button. Then If I don't want that number in my memory any longer, I can click MC to completely clear the entire memory.

So far I have done a very rough layout at the bottom of my code, trying to get the event to store the number into a new variable, then just calling he variable when I click Memory Restore. Then When I click memory clear I just set the variable to ="" but nothing seems to be working.

JS:

```
//Changing colors of operation colors 

//Multiply Color
const colorMultiply = document.getElementById('multiply')
colorMultiply.style.backgroundColor = "green" //Makes Color Green

//Divide Color
const colorDivide = document.getElementById('divide')
colorDivide.style.backgroundColor = "red"//Makes Color Red

//subtract color
const colorSubtract = document.getElementById('subtract')
colorSubtract.style.backgroundColor="blue"//Makes Color Blue

//add color
const colorAdd = document.getElementById('add')
colorAdd.style.backgroundColor="yellow"//Makes Color Yellow


//change font of numbers to blue (I did it like this incase anyone wants to color of a single number)
//Makes it easier for you to change a colour of one button
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1')
number1.style.color="blue"
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2')
number2.style.color="blue"
const number3 = document.getElementById('number3')
number3.style.color="blue"
const number4 = document.getElementById('number4')
number4.style.color="blue"
const number5 = document.getElementById('number5')
number5.style.color="blue"
const number6 = document.getElementById('number6')
number6.style.color="blue"
const number7 = document.getElementById('number7')
number7.style.color="blue"
const number8 = document.getElementById('number8')
number8.style.color="blue"
const number9 = document.getElementById('number9')
number9.style.color="blue"
const number0 = document.getElementById('number0')
number0.style.color="blue"
const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal')
decimal.style.color="blue"

//Changing color of the clear button
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
clear.style.color="white"
clear.style.backgroundColor="black"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Then we want to insert `memoryStoreButton` before the `clear` button:
var memoryStoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryStoreButton.innerHTML = "MS";
clear.before(memoryStoreButton); //puts button before clear

// Then we want the `memoryClearButton` before `memoryStoreButton`
var memoryClearButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryClearButton.innerHTML = "MC";
memoryStoreButton.before(memoryClearButton);//puts button before clear

// and finally, the `memoryRestoreButton` before `memoryClearButton`
var memoryRestoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryRestoreButton.innerHTML = "MR";
memoryClearButton.before(memoryRestoreButton);//puts button before clear

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//What number buttons are pressed
var numButton = document.querySelectorAll(".btn8");
var showNum = document.querySelector(".screen8");


numButton.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.innerHTML == "C"){
      return showNum.value = "";
    } else if (event.target.innerHTML == "=") {
      return;
    }
    let view = event.target.dataset.num;
    showNum.value += view;
  });
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//When equal is pressed it calculates the numbers, and if no numbers were entered there will be a error mesage
var equalButton = document.querySelector("#equals")
equalButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(showNum.value == ""){
    return alert("Please Enter a Value"); // If no numbers are being displayed, error alert.
  }
  showNum.value = showNum.value + "=" + eval(showNum.value);
});

//Align test to the right of screen
document.getElementById("numberBox").style.textAlign = "right";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Change colors when hovering over buttons
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
function addButtonHandlers(btn) {

  // make black button on mouseover
  btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  });

  // make grey button on mouseout
  btn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
  });
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Making a memory store button functional
memoryStoreButton.addEventListener('click',function(event){
var memoryStoreValue = (showNum.value)  
})

//Making memory Clear Button functional

//Making a memory Restore Button functional
memoryStoreButton.addEventListener('click',function(event){
showNum.memoryStoreValue
})

//Making memory Clear Button functional
memoryStoreButton.addEventListener('click',function(event){
memoryStoreValue= ""
})
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<title> Calculator 8 </title>
 <script src="fp.js" defer></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fp.css">

</head>
<body>
 <section class="calculator8">
    <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="calcScreeng" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">C</button>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;

}

.calculator8{
 flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.screen8{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 5rem;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 background: rgb(41,41,56);
 color: white;
 border:none;
}

.buttons8{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

button{
 flex:0 0 25%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.25rem 0;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}

.btn-kground: rgb(224,224,224);
}

.btn8{
 font-size: 4rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways to do that.

I believe you should start simply by storing in the DOM, with the button.

This is simple but good for learning, because you will see the value in your debugger, by just inspecting the given element.

```js
memoryRestoreButton.onclick = (function(){
  // Store the value
  memoryRestoreButton.dataset.whatever = numberBox.value
  // Read the stored value
  console.log(memoryRestoreButton.dataset.whatever)
})
```

```html
<button id="memoryRestoreButton">MR</button>
<input id="numberBox" value="8888">
```

Now the element has a new attribute `data-whatever`, and you can retrieve the value from anywhere in your code.

[image]

---

Your code modified. Notice the calculator is not working because it miss a library that you didn't included. Also your code is using `eval()` for the calculation, this is insecure. Use New Function() instead. This code is years old, if it's an exercise given to you, you should raise a flag to your teacher.

```js
//Changing colors of operation colors 

//Multiply Color
const colorMultiply = document.getElementById('multiply')
colorMultiply.style.backgroundColor = "green" //Makes Color Green

//Divide Color
const colorDivide = document.getElementById('divide')
colorDivide.style.backgroundColor = "red"//Makes Color Red

//subtract color
const colorSubtract = document.getElementById('subtract')
colorSubtract.style.backgroundColor="blue"//Makes Color Blue

//add color
const colorAdd = document.getElementById('add')
colorAdd.style.backgroundColor="yellow"//Makes Color Yellow


//change font of numbers to blue (I did it like this incase anyone wants to color of a single number)
//Makes it easier for you to change a colour of one button
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1')
number1.style.color="blue"
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2')
number2.style.color="blue"
const number3 = document.getElementById('number3')
number3.style.color="blue"
const number4 = document.getElementById('number4')
number4.style.color="blue"
const number5 = document.getElementById('number5')
number5.style.color="blue"
const number6 = document.getElementById('number6')
number6.style.color="blue"
const number7 = document.getElementById('number7')
number7.style.color="blue"
const number8 = document.getElementById('number8')
number8.style.color="blue"
const number9 = document.getElementById('number9')
number9.style.color="blue"
const number0 = document.getElementById('number0')
number0.style.color="blue"
const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal')
decimal.style.color="blue"

//Changing color of the clear button
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
clear.style.color="white"
clear.style.backgroundColor="black"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Then we want to insert `memoryStoreButton` before the `clear` button:
var memoryStoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryStoreButton.innerHTML = "MS";
clear.before(memoryStoreButton); //puts button before clear

// Then we want the `memoryClearButton` before `memoryStoreButton`
var memoryClearButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryClearButton.innerHTML = "MC";
memoryStoreButton.before(memoryClearButton);//puts button before clear

// and finally, the `memoryRestoreButton` before `memoryClearButton`
var memoryRestoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryRestoreButton.innerHTML = "MR";
memoryClearButton.before(memoryRestoreButton);//puts button before clear

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//What number buttons are pressed
var numButton = document.querySelectorAll(".btn8");
var showNum = document.querySelector(".screen8");


numButton.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.innerHTML == "C"){
      return showNum.value = "";
    } else if (event.target.innerHTML == "=") {
      return;
    }
    let view = event.target.dataset.num;
    showNum.value += view;
  });
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//When equal is pressed it calculates the numbers, and if no numbers were entered there will be a error mesage
var equalButton = document.querySelector("#equals")
equalButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(showNum.value == ""){
    return alert("Please Enter a Value"); // If no numbers are being displayed, error alert.
  }
  showNum.value = showNum.value + "=" + eval(showNum.value);
});

//Align test to the right of screen
document.getElementById("numberBox").style.textAlign = "right";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Change colors when hovering over buttons
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
function addButtonHandlers(btn) {

  // make black button on mouseover
  btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  });

  // make grey button on mouseout
  btn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
  });
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
let memory = 0
//Making a memory store button functional
memoryStoreButton.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  memory = numberBox.value;
})

//Making memory Clear Button functional

//Making a memory Restore Button functional
memoryClearButton.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  memory = 0;
})

//Making memory Clear Button functional
memoryRestoreButton.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  numberBox.value = memory;
})
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;

}

.calculator8{
 flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.screen8{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 5rem;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 background: rgb(41,41,56);
 color: white;
 border:none;
}

.buttons8{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

button{
 flex:0 0 25%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.25rem 0;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}

.btn-kground: rgb(224,224,224);
}

.btn8{
 font-size: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<title> Calculator 8 </title>

</head>
<body>
 <section class="calculator8">
    <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="calcScreeng" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">C</button>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be able to use the same procedure for every button. Just create an event, like the example, but change with the id. Here I used `memoryRestoreButton` because the button element has the same id. It is simply calling the element like `document.getElementById("memoryRestoreButton")`, same thing.

Comment: so for store it would be:                                             
 memoryStoreButton.onclick = (function(){
  memoryStoreButton.dataset.whatever = numberBox.value
  console.log(memoryStoreButton.dataset.whatever)
})?

Comment: Yes! Try it, and hack around! Notice the use of `whatever`, you can define any words here: `memoryStoreButton.onclick = (function(){ memoryStoreButton.dataset.memoryValue = numberBox.value;console.log(memoryStoreButton.dataset.memoryValue); })` , so the new attribute will be `data-memoryValue`. You can create multiple dataset attributes and set them on any element. Anywhere in your code, when you need the value you can just use `memoryStoreButton.dataset.memoryValue`

Comment: would you be able to use my code in a snippet, I'm just getting a bit confused here.

Answer (score 1):

you can use localStorage

**To Store**

```
localStorage.setItem("result", 5); // or localStorage.result=5;
```

**To Get**

```
localStorage.getItem("result")  // or localStorage.result;
```

**To Clear**

```
localStorage.setItem("result",""); // or localStorage.result="";
```

Comment: Yes! But beware the data will stay in the localStorage for the  whole domain.

Comment: SessionStorage may be what he needs.